# Duvida qual variável passar do meu Select

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp

Tenho dois selects, os dois consultam o banco de dados. Tenho Equipamentos, e Operações...

[image: Selects]

Ao selecionar o equipamento x no select, vou consultar o banco de dados para o select Operações puxar somente as Operações que não estão em uso de acordo com o equipamento que selecionei.

Onde esta "variável" na consulta de operação, é que devo passar o que foi selecionado no select equipamentos, para mostrar somente as Operações disponíveis de acordo com o que selecionei no select de equipamentos.

mas não sei o que devo passar ali como variável do select.

MEU SELECT DO EQUIPAMENTOS

```
<select name='field-number-key-COD_EQUIP' id='field-number-key-COD_EQUIP' type='text' class='form-control input-lg'lang='Equipamento,N'
onkeypress='Javascript:return only_alphabetic_acentos(this,event);' disabled >
<option value='' selected>-- Selecione --</option>
<struts_logic:iterate id="arrHH_EQUIPAMENTOS" name="collHH_EQUIPAMENTOS" scope="page" type="java.util.ArrayList">
<option value='<%=arrHH_EQUIPAMENTOS.get(0).toString()%>'
<%=arrHH_EQUIPAMENTOS.get(0).toString().equals(COD_EQUIP) ? "selected" : ""%> >
<%=arrHH_EQUIPAMENTOS.get(1).toString()%>
</option>
</struts_logic:iterate>
</select>
```

MEU SELECT DE OPERAÇÃO

```
<select name='field-number-key-CODOPERACAO' id='field-number-key-CODOPERACAO' type='text' class='form-control input-lg' lang='Operação,N' onkeypress='Javascript:return only_alphabetic_acentos(this,event);' disabled >
<option value='' selected>-- Selecione --</option>
<struts_logic:iterate id="arrHH_OPER_CAMPO" name="collHH_OPER_CAMPO" scope="page" type="java.util.ArrayList">
<option value='<%=arrHH_OPER_CAMPO.get(0).toString()%>'
<%=arrHH_OPER_CAMPO.get(0).toString().equals(CODOPERACAO) ? "selected" : ""%> >
<%=arrHH_OPER_CAMPO.get(1).toString()%>
</option>
</struts_logic:iterate>
</select>
```

CONSULTA NO BANCO PARA EQUIPAMENTOS

```
<executequery:query resultSet="collHH_EQUIPAMENTOS" listPages="collListPagesHH_EQUIPAMENTOS"
sqlSelect="select s.codequip, s.descrequip from hh_equipamentos s where s.action<>'D' order by s.descrequip" page="0" conPool="4" >
</executequery:query>
```

CONSULTA NO BANCO PARA OPERAÇÃO

```
<executequery:query resultSet="collHH_OPER_CAMPO" listPages="collListPagesHH_OPER_CAMPO"
sqlSelect="SELECT CODOPERCAMPO, DESCROPERCAMPO FROM hh_oper_campo O
WHERE O.CODOPERCAMPO NOT IN (SELECT CODOPERACAO FROM MED_EQUIP M WHERE m.COD_EQUIP = <variavel>); " page="0" conPool="4" >
</executequery:query>
```

Comment: O seu `m.COD_EQUIP` deve receber o valor `<option value='<%=arrHH_EQUIPAMENTOS.get(0).toString()%>'` pois pelo que me parece é aqui que o código é definido. Você teria que chamar o value desse input pela id/name. Recomendo evitar scriptlets no seu código. Isso era usado há quase 20 anos atrás. Leia, no mínimo, sobre jstl.

Comment: Problema é que é um sistema antigo eu apenas faço algumas alterações, mas como não tem nada documentado e também está bem ultrapassado varias coisas, estou tendo bastante dificuldade em algumas coisas, agradeço vou testar do jeito que você passou !

Comment: @rhenesys esse struts_logic:iterate que tem o id/name é onde está armazenando o value das options ?

desculpa pela pergunta nunca peguei essa estrutura antes

Answer (score 0):

O seu m.COD_EQUIP deve receber o valor ' pois pelo que me parece é aqui que o código é definido. Você teria que chamar o value desse input pela id/name. Recomendo evitar scriptlets no seu código. Isso era usado há quase 20 anos atrás. Leia, no mínimo, sobre jstl.

EDIT:

`id="arrHH_EQUIPAMENTOS" name="collHH_EQUIPAMENTOS"` chamando a `id` em javascript você teria o selected value. Usando JSP você teria que chamar `name`.

Comment: ainda não deu, como posso por exemplo, quando eu selecionar o select de maquinas, ai faz o select de operação...
tipo não deu erro nenhum do jeto que falou, mas parece que ele carrega logo quando inicio a pagina, então por mais que eu seleciono algo no select de maquinas, o select de operação sempre aparece as mesmas coisas

Comment: SELECT CODOPERCAMPO, DESCROPERCAMPO FROM hh_oper_campo WHERE CODOPERCAMPO NOT IN (SELECT CODOPERACAO FROM MED_EQUIP M WHERE M.codoperacao = CODOPERCAMPO and M.COD_EQUIP = "+ request.getParameter("collHH_EQUIPAMENTOS")

já tentei com o id também

Comment: se alguém tiver algum outro raciocínio de como posso fazer, aceito sugestões kkk